# 403 error due to quota exceeded. But quota isn't exceeded?

Tags: java, server, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My Project: https://gitlab.com/RandomHashTags/united-livestreams-server

- YouTube refresh with new content [here](https://gitlab.com/RandomHashTags/united-livestreams-server/blob/master/src/main/java/me/randomhashtags/ulserver/Platform.java#L254)
- YouTube update existing content [here](https://gitlab.com/RandomHashTags/united-livestreams-server/blob/master/src/main/java/me/randomhashtags/ulserver/Platform.java#L304)

## Short rundown what is happening

- I host a Java Server on a VPS
- My YouTube Data v3 **Quota Limit: 10,000 per day**
- Server updates youtube content with a fresh search every 20 minutes

  - cost **109** quota each search, for a total of **7,848 a day**
- Server updates existing live channels every 3 minutes 32 seconds

  - cost **5** quota each update, for a total of **2040 a day**
- #### Total Theoretical Quota Usage: 9,888 per day
- Get error 403 (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#gdata.CoreErrorDomain)

  - I am assuming it is **403 quotaExceeded** because what else could it logically be?
- Everything works as expected, even in my ios app.
- NOTE: I also use Twitch and Mixer API, and update at the same time. YouTube is the only one with the error.

## Here is my graph

LEGEND

1. Booted server for first time for production
2. Restarted server because 403 error the day before (stopped updating content)
   [image: Quota Usage]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This may be service specific rather than code related.

As of late, I have also been receiving more frequent 403 errors via an automated youtube-dl script. I suspect the quota is being applied to an IP range or block. Using a VPN to change my IP/location immediately solved the issue. After waiting a day, the 403 response disappears for myself.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'll look into a VPN